# Is it possible to hide a row from a dynamic table?

Tags: php, html

I currently have a dynamic table which fetches information from my database.  What I really would like to do now, is to be able to hide a row. Is this do-able with only HTML and PHP or do I have to make an other table and INSERT the information into the new table and remove the previous?

Comment: You could either render your table (via php) with some classes on your table row (class="hidden") then using css, you can set a rule for that class to `display:none;`. That would hide the row as soon as the page has loaded.

Or, you could use some javascript to hide the row(s) after the page has already been rendered. It depends on how/when you need to hide the row.

Comment: There are literally a thousand ways to do this. What have you done so far and into which problem did you run?

Comment: I'm kinda new to PHP and MYSQL, and were forced to complete this project. But it's just a simple assignment manager, where the admins can add new assignments and such. My final step is to be able to press "Done" and hide the row when the assignment is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new column to your database table called "is_published" with a value of 0 or 1. The rows that you want to hide would need "is_published" set to 0 and the others set to 1.

Then when you pull the data from the database put a where clause in like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE is_published = '1'";
```

Comment: Yeah, that might work. Thanks!

Comment: Why use the database for something that can be handled on the client?

Comment: I'd probably avoid using quotes here - the database engine will have to pointlessly cast your integer/boolean column to string, when there is no need for it to do so.

Comment: So, just --- is_published = 1;